# How C++ destructor works

Tags: c++, destructor, raii, c++-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Object destruction in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403055/object-destruction-in-c)
>   [destructor checking in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712020/destructor-checking-in-c)

I want a simple program to see how destructor works in C++?

I basically do not understand when the destructor is called.