# c++ "new" keyword comparision to java

Tags: java, c++, object, pointers, member-initialization

first of all i hope this isnt a dublicate. Im am a java programmer and changing to c++ now.
In java you can do like this

```
 Object obj = new Object();
```

and to my understanding you can the same thing in c++ (seeing how obj in java will only be saved in the variable as a reference) like this:

```
Object* obj = new Object();
```

My question is this: How long does this object live? does it live as long as the pointer does ? also, is this possible to do will member initilazion of an object ? And if so will the object live as long as the pointer is saved as a member vairable (until that object you store it in is destroyes)?

Srry for any typos. Have a nice day/nigth!

Comment: there is no `garbage collection` in c++, you have to free the memory yourself

Comment: `Srry for any typos.` - Was that typo by purpose?

Comment: Despite similar syntax in some places, C++ and Java are *very* different in their approach to this topic (and related issues). A comparison of the two data models would turn into a full description of both.

Comment: @C.Lang Or better yet, use a smart pointer.

Comment: @moose haha i didn´t even think about that. Just a reflex from gamming ^^

Comment: If you only need the object for the current scope, just du `Object obj;`. That's like some orders of magnitude faster for a simple object. The object is automatically destroyed at the end of the scope, with an automatic call to its destructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object destruction in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403055/object-destruction-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

The object lives until someone calls `delete` on the pointer that points to it. You should not use `new` and `delete` unless you are implementing some library functionality where there is no other option, and you *really* know what you are doing. The default action should be not to use `new` directly, unless it is to initialize a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) or to insert into some class that takes care of memory management for you.

This would be the C++ way of creating a default constructed instance of `Object`:

```
Object obj; // calls the default constructor
```

Comment: ok:( i will keep that in mind. Trying to find a way to initialize a vector as a member variable. Maby i should make a new question about that :P

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman you don't have to do anything special. The default constructor of the vector does something sensible.

Comment: AFAIK the most common garbage collector for C++ is the **[Boehm collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)**. It's been used since at least C++03. The C++11 standard added some minimal support for garbage collection, namely **`std::declare_reachable`**, **`std::undeclare_reachable`**, **`std::declare_no_pointers`**, **`std::undeclare_no_pointers`** and **`std::get_pointer_safety`**.

Answer (score 2):

**How long does this object live?**

Until you explicitially `delete` it.  Unlike in Java, objects in C++ that are dynamically instantiated via `new` have user-controlled lifetimes and are not garbage collected, so they are not automatically freed when all references to them disappear.  If you want that behavior, there are classes like `std::auto_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` to handle that for you.

Comment: I would add that `auto_ptr` is deprecated and `shared_ptr` is almost always overkill. New code should use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Java objects aren't reference-counted either.

Comment: @EJP: I meant garbage collected. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You create an object like this.

In the .h file, you have the follow Object *foo;

In the .cpp class, you initialise the class similar to java.

foo = new Object();

You then delete it using the delete keyword - so delete foo in this case.

I'm in a similar boat to you. I highly recommend getting your head around pointers (the * thing) - it's really powerful.

Edit: as said above, you can also just do Object foo to create the object on the stack, rather than the heap.

Comment: yh :P im in the swamp of * and &. I Know the diffrence between them, but when i come to initializing objects, passing them in to function ect. So confusing when to use what :P

Comment: I'm not quite there with & yet. Baby steps are best. I used to writer 30-50 lines of code with java, press compile and hope for the best! I find myself planning and saving and compiling with every key press!

Comment: i recomend you watch thenewBoston c++ tutorials on youtube :) a bit slow but he explains alot of stuff. Tho its kinda basic stuff

Answer (score 0):

In C or C++, it will live until it's deleted.  You typically want to wrap any resource allocation/deallocation (which can include calls to new/delete and malloc/free) in a ctor dtor pair.  e.g.

```
class ObjectManager
{
public:
    ObjectManager()
        : mObjectPtr(0)
    {
        mObjectPtr = new Object();
    }

    ~ObjectManager()
    {
        delete mObject;
    }
private:
    Object* mObjectPtr;
};
```

If you use that, you should add some error handling in case something goes wrong in new.

Comment: Not in C, since C does not have `new` and `delete`.

Comment: This is this RAII everybody is talking about rigth ? and while this is good, im unsure how this will solve my put it as a member variable issue i have :O

Comment: A destructor is not enough.  If you're going to go this route, you also need either define or disable (at least) the copy constructor and the assignment operator.  And for C++11 you should also define a move constructor and a move assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed garbage collector in C++ so it will live until it is explicitly deleted.

If you want to use pointers and like something a bit more managed you can use a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> Obj = new Object();
```

There are a few different types of smart pointers, as per the linked answer, but basically a smart pointer will automatically destroy the object once it goes out of scope.

As for member initialisation part of your question you can do

```
TestMe()
{
  Object Obj();

  //Do something with object

}
```

Then Obj gets created on the stack and is destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.

Comment: -1 "There is no garbage collector in C++ so..." is incorrect. there is no guaranteed garbage collection, though: you have to explicitly use a garbage collector, and the language's support for that is pretty limited. it would have helped to read the other answers and comments before posting your own.