# Lifetime and memory setup of this struct

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, struct

given a struct in the form ( declared before the `main()` or after )

```
struct
{
    ...
} bar;
```

I don't know how to manage this and how to treat this kind of object.

In general I would like a 360° answer about this but I also have few questions:

- is this equivalent to declaring a `static` struct ?
- it's legal and safe in C++11 ?
- how to access bar by reference ?

For the last one I have prepared a small snippet [here](http://pastebin.com/JEVWyuM9), that doesn't works but shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Also See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11712472/14065

Comment: Please don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted if it solves your problem. It will ease searching for the answer for those who come later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's global object of unnamed struct. You cannot use this type as argument to function (since you doesn't know real type of the object). You can use decltype for this, but it doesn't needed since it's global object. It's legal and safe.

```
#include <iostream>

struct
{
    double k1 =  0.123;
} bar;

int foo(decltype(bar)& a)
{
    return a.k1-1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(bar) << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

[example](http://ideone.com/XMkhoi)

Really, since you have only one global object of this struct - you simply can use

```
#include <iostream>

struct
{
    double k1 =  0.123;
} bar;

int foo()
{
    return bar.k1-1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: how without using decltype ? Also it's true that the C++11 standard doesn't provide anonymous structs ?

Comment: @user2384250 you doesn't know real type. compiler knows. decltype allows you to use this type (may be boost can help too). There are no anonymous structs, there are unnamed structs.

Comment: @ForEveR Is `double k1 =  0.123;` statement valid?

Comment: @bikram990 in C++11? Why not?

Comment: However it is not legal in C++03

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a *global variable*. You can access it from any function or method in this compilation unit. The correct way of declaring it (in regard to your snippet) would be:

```
struct foo
{
    double k = 1.23;
};

foo bar;
```

Now you can simply pass it by reference like this:

```
void f(foo & b)
{
    b.k = 34.5;
}
```

In your snippet, bar is a variable of type being an unnamed struct:

```
struct <unnamed>
{
    double k = 1.23;
} bar;
```

Since you did not give any name to your type, you're unable to pass it as a parameter to functions in the classic way. C++11 allows you to do so using the decltype directive:

```
struct
{
    double k = 1.23;
} bar;

void f(decltype(bar) & b)
{
    b.k = 3.45;
}
```

As for your questions:

- It is not the same as a static struct. Static variables behave in a little different way. Static classes (= structs) too.
- It *is* legal and safe to use global variables in C++11, but it is strongly advised *not* to use them, because they may easily break program's logic or architecture. Instead, one should use static classes or singletons.

Comment: your suggestion for the new interface for f() doesn't work for me, it's also strange because bar& it's not legal anyway under my g++ 4.7.2

Comment: Which declaration you are talking about? I never used `bar &` in my codes.

Answer (score 0):

No.  `static` is a storage attribute.  A `struct` is like any other data type:  it can be `static`, `volatile`, `auto`, `extern`, `and` others defined by some implementations.

It is legal and safe.

Reference such a structure like this:

```
struct {
     int   field1, field2;
     double  yada, yada2, yada3;
} bar1, bar2;

bar1.yada3 = 3.14159265358979;   // assign a field in the struct
bar2 = bar1;   // copy contents of bar1 to bar2
```

Comment: how to do this for methods ? how to let a method access bar by reference ?

Answer (score 0):

1> bar is only single instance of its type. You can not have another instance of same type as bar. Its type is unnamed type struct, just like anonymous union.  It is legal to have one such. It is more like global static(but not it is not static) just because you cannot refer it by `extern` keyword in other file.Any hack you have to refer it in other file ...?

3> It is legal to have it.

4> You can not declare reference to variable whose type you do not know. .Although u can access/modify same object anywhere in the file, so no need of reference. References are used to remove * and -> from code, mainly, otherwise what references do, is all possible with pointer.

Comment: are you sure that's legal ? I haven't found anything related to anonymous structs in the C++ 11 standard. Can you provide code displaying access by reference ?

Comment: 1 isn't really true.  As has been pointed out by others, you can get its type in a template (or in C++11, also by `decltype`).  And within the instantiation of the template function, you can create other instances.

Answer (score 0):

> is this equivalent to declaring a `static` struct ?

No, you'd use the `static` keyword for that, as for any other `static` variable. It's declaring a global variable, i.e. with static storage duration and external linkage, equivalent to:

```
struct Bar {...};
Bar bar;
```

> it's legal and safe in C++11 ?

Yes.

> how to access bar by reference ?

Since the type has no name, it has to be inferred, either by template argument deduction or, in C++11:

```
auto & ref = bar;

template <typename Bar> void bar_by_ref(Bar & bar) { 
    /* do something with bar */ 
}
```

Alternatively, in C++11, the type can be extracted by `decltype`:

```
decltype(bar) & ref = bar;
```